# Excel Macro, read a worksheet, select range of data, copy selection

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a macro that reads a worksheet of GeoTechnical data, selects the data based off a value in a particular row, select that row and continue reading until the end of worksheet.  Once all rows are selected, I then need to copy those rows into a new worksheet.  I haven't done VBA in about 10 years, so just trying to get back into things.

For example, I want the macro to read the worksheet, when column "I" contains the word "Run" on a particular row, I want to then select from that row, A:AM. Continue reading through the worksheet until the end of it.  The end of the document is tricky as there are up to 10-15 blank rows sometimes in between groups of data in the worksheet.  If there is more then 25 blank rows, then the document would be at the end.  Once everything is selected, I then need to copy the selection for pasting into a new worksheet. Here is the code I have thus far, but I'm unable to get a selection:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub GeoTechDB()
      Dim x As String
      Dim BlankCount As Integer
      ' Select first line of data.
      Range("I2").Select
      ' Set search variable value and counter.
      x = "Run"
      BlankCount = 0
      ' Set Do loop to read cell value, increment or reset counter and stop loop at end    'document when there
      ' is more then 25 blank cells in column "I", copy final selection
      Do Until BlankCount > 25
         ' Check active cell for search value "Run".
         If ActiveCell.Value = x Then
            'select the range of data when "Run" is found
            ActiveCell.Range("A:AM").Select
            'set counter to 0
            BlankCount = 0
            'Step down 1 row from present location
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
         Else
            'Step down 1 row from present location
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            'if cell is empty then increment the counter
            BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
         End If
      Loop
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see various things wrong with your code. If I understood properly what you want, this code should deliver it:

```
          ' Set Do loop to read cell value, increment or reset counter and stop loop at end    'document when there
          ' is more then 25 blank cells in column "I", copy final selection

  Dim x As String
  Dim BlankCount As Integer
  Range("I2").Select
  x = "Run"
  BlankCount = 0
  Dim found As Boolean
  Dim curVal As String
  Dim rowCount As Long
  Dim completed As Boolean
  rowCount = 2  
  Dim allRanges(5000) As Range
  Dim rangesCount As Long

  rangesCount = -1          
  notFirst = False
  Do Until completed
     rowCount = rowCount + 1

     curVal = Range("I" & CStr(rowCount)).Value

     If curVal = x Then
         found = True
         BlankCounter = 0
         rangesCount = rangesCount + 1
         Set allRanges(rangesCount) = Range("A" & CStr(rowCount) & ":AM" & CStr(rowCount))

     ElseIf (found) Then
        If (IsEmpty(Range("I" & CStr(rowCount)).Value)) Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
        If BlankCount > 25 Then Exit Do
     End If

     If (rowCount >= 5000) Then Exit Do 'In the safest-side condition to avoid an infinite loop in case of not of finding what is intended. You can delete this line
  Loop

  If (rangesCount > 0) Then
     Dim curRange As Variant
     Dim allTogether As Range
     Set allTogether = allRanges(0)
     For Each curRange In allRanges
           If (Not curRange Is Nothing) Then Set allTogether = Union(curRange, allTogether)
     Next curRange

     allTogether.Select
  End If
```

It starts iterating through column I from I2, until finding the word "Run". In this moment, it starts to count cells until reaching 25 (when the loop is exited and the corresponding range, as defined by the last row and the one at "Run", is selected). You are talking about blank cells but your code does not check that, also I am not sure what to do in case of finding a non-blank cell (restarting the counter?). Please, elaborate more on this.

Comment: I realized I had nothing about the blanks in my code after posting.  I want to iterate through column "I".  If a blank is found I want the counter to increase.  If the word "run" is found in column "I", I want to select columns A:AM for that row, reset the blanks counter to 0 and continue the iteration down column "I" Once column "I" has 25 blank rows continuously then we have found the end of the document and I want to copy the selected cells. Does that make sense?

Comment: @MMayer sure. This is what my code does with the exception of accounting for blank cells: once the "Start" is found just counts 25 cells. I will update it right now such that it will count just the blank ones.

Comment: @MMayer done. Summary to make sure: starts in I2 and keeps going down until finding "Run"; when it finds it stores the value of the row (startRow). Since this moment it counts empty cells. When the number of empty cells is higher than 25, the loop is exited and the range selected. The range is defined by columns A and AM, the aforementioned startRow and the last row before exiting the loop. Is this what you want?

Comment: Sounds like what I want, I will try your code and see if I get the desired result, thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: @MMayer It was the () after Select. Sorry.

Comment: It's Ok, I should have noticed that...been way too long since I've done any programming!

Comment: This is the closest I have been with this.  The problem I'm encountering with the current code, is that it is only selects the last "run" and the 25 blank rows at the end of the document.  When "run" is encountered in the worksheet, anywhere in column "I" I want to select columns "A:AM" for that row.  Once there are 25 blank rows continuously, then the document is at it's end and I want to copy all the above selection.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @MMayer Sure. I thought that there was just one "Run". Will update the code. The final blank rows have to be selected or not?

Comment: the final blank rows do not need to be selected...the final blank rows are just indicating the end of document.  There are many "Run" in the document.

Comment: @MMayer I corrected the code. If there are many rows, perhaps you want to remove the in-the-safest-side condition, exiting the loop on row 5000. You can delete it if you want ( If (rowCount >= 5000) Then Exit Do)

Comment: There likely won't be more then 5000 rows, I think the max is around 1500, so I will leave it in there.

Comment: Almost there....it seems there is problem with the last line again, it gives me a run time error " Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" Sorry for the hassle, I can't thank you enough for your expertise and help.

Comment: @MMayer this time everything should be OK. The only problem I see is that the range is formed by too many elements (too many relevant rows) but I haven't ever seen such a thing. Can you please put a break point of this this line and see what is the value of finalRange?

Comment: The value of finalRange, was a large selection of Ranges.  I ran the code and I got the same RunTime error again.  When I stop it before then, no error, but no selection.  The values in finalRange looked correct, but they were not making the selection

Comment: @MMayer The reason why no selection is made is because the code crashes when trying to perform the action. The string is too long this is the problem. I will deliver a different approach better for so many ranges. Give me some minutes.

Comment: I was just coming to that conclusion.  There are a lot of ranges and can be many depending on the size/length of the DrillHole we are extracting the data from.  For example, one worksheet could contain say 20 "pages", each page has data we need to select from A15:AM15 to A43:AM43 (block selection) then again for another page A68:AM68 to A96:AM96 (another block selection in the same worksheet)...and so on. So there can potentially be a very large selection of ranges. You are seriously my hero, thank you

Comment: @MMayer OK, here goes my last shot: I stored all the ranges in an array (with a size of 5000: there shouldn't be any problem) and join them together by relying on the Range object. The problem you got is because the size of the string when using dictionary-arrays, like Range, is limited (not sure, but don't think that too much more than 200 characters). This time there shouldn't be any restriction... Your hero?! No, I am just a poor idiot. Get a proper hero: a rich/famous one LOL.

Comment: Lol, fair enough, well you're my hero for the day, I don't think I would have figured this one out on my own. Well, this is super close, it made the right selection for the first two sections, but didn't go right to the end of the document.  There are about 13 more sections that need to be selected in this sheet, not sure why it stopped so suddenly.  But you've helped me enough, thanks so much for everything, I should be able to get it to work from here....should...

Comment: @MMayer No problem. Have fun :)

Comment: Problem solved, we just needed to reset the BlankCounter to 0 when "Run" was found.  All good!

Comment: @MMayer my bad. Actually this was present in the first version but I guess that overlooked it in one of my corrections. Will correct the code right away.

Comment: It was no problem at all, I actually fixed it myself with a very simple piece of code. I will show you in your code above.  Thanks again!

Comment: @MMayer thanks, but actually is already fixed in my code. I did it yesterday right after posting my previous comment. As said, I did account for that since the first moment but with all this code updating (+ and the fact of being a bit late here... around 1am :)) I missed this bit: it is just the "BlankCounter = 0" line inside the condition. But you have certainly be very nice and helpful, thanks.

Comment: @MMayer PS: in any case, next time, please be (much) more clear in the description of the problem and you exact conditions. If I would have known from the start the high numbers of lines involved (in a first moment, I thought that there was just one case!!) would have been taken a different approach; also a better description of the exact conditions would have allowed me to deliver a proper code "in one go" (take a look at Tim Williams' code he didn't got what you meant (and he is pretty competent))...

Comment: @MMayer ...You being nice + I being tired allowed this long commenting thing, otherwise I wouldn't have done it (or anyone else): the clearer is the problem, the quicker will be the solution. I guess that you would have also preferred a quick and to-the-point solution: keep the being-nice bit that is certainly a good thing but improve the clarity of your question/conditions in the future :)

Comment: I will take all that into consideration most definitely, I thought I was clear, but after reading it again, not so much.  Thanks again for the tips and the help....it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GeoTechDB()
Const COLS_TO_COPY As Long = 39
Dim x As String, c As Range, rngCopy As Range
Dim BlankCount As Integer

    Set c = Range("I2")

    x = "Run"
    BlankCount = 0

    Do Until BlankCount > 25

    If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
        BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
    Else
        BlankCount = 0
        If c.Value = x Then
           If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
               Set rngCopy = c.EntireRow.Cells(1) _
                              .Resize(1, COLS_TO_COPY)
           Else
                Set rngCopy = Application.Union(rngCopy, _
                             c.EntireRow.Cells(1) _
                               .Resize(1, COLS_TO_COPY))
           End If
        End If
    End If
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheet2.Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i like short codes:

```
Sub column_I_contains_run()
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then Selection.Autofilter 'if an autofilter already exists this is removed

        ActiveSheet.Range("$I$1:$I$" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 9).End(xlUp).Row).Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*run*"

    Range("A1:AM" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 9).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

now you just have to paste it into a new sheet, what could be automated also...

Comment: Shorter codes are something nice-to-have but only after two other conditions are met: they deliver accurate results and are as adaptable as bigger ones. Your code does not deliver what the OP wants (selects all the initial rows until the first "Run") also modifies the worksheet in a way which perhaps is not allowed by the OP requirements (e.g., performing this selection in parallel with a pasting to other cells in the same worksheet -> if you are not sure of something, better don't implement a so "aggressive" approach)...

Comment: ... additionally your code does not account for the 25 limit; in principle, this is just to know the end of the worksheet but might also be a further reason (-> it is one of the input requirements of the OP and, unless being completely sure, better not ignoring it). On the adaptabe/extensible front, there is no discussion that your approach is highly inflexible: not only because of the aforementioned modification of the whole worksheet, but because of the nature of a filter (vs. a loop, what the other answerers and the OP himself used). Imagine a further condition "paste into Run2 cells".

Comment: the op does not write something about "all rows until first 'run'" He does indeed state that the 25-limit is only there to find the end of the document. And I fo not see any Problem with a paste-operation, if you have a closer look at the code 'Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select'

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my point: the OP does NOT want to copy all the rows until the first "Run" (just the rows with "Run"), but your solution does that (in case that the first "Run" is not in the first row). Regarding your other comments, I have just given you my impressions about this kind of solutions, you are free to continue thinking in the way you want. PS: you are right on my paste example; I chose a wrong one.

Comment: Hi @Varocarbas, only the very first row is copied, not all until the first "run"; that can be solved by selecting the range starting by A2 instead of A1. As I am using this Kind of code a lot, i would be interested what other risks/inflexibilities you see. by removing the filter after the "copy" also the worksheet would not be changed in the end either.

Comment: Sorry to correct you but this is not what I see. If I open a new Excel file, copy Run in cells 3 and 6 and execute your code, I get rows 1-3 and 6 selected.

Comment: Regarding the inflexibility, try to account for further variables (like the proposed 25 rows). Imagine that the requirements change to: "select just the Run rows after 25". Or select all but change the backcolor of the ones falling with 25. Your code wouldn't account for any variation other than for ones involving the whole selection. The loop can be easily adapted to completely different situations just by changing one of the conditions or by adding new ones. You can rely on these kind of approaches to deal with more or less simple situations, not changing too much.

Comment: PS: shorter code does not mean easier to be built. Usually, creating these smaller codes (delivering the functionality you are after) takes longer than relying on loop-based approaches (and, as said, will have serious problems if the conditions change appreciably). If you usually rely on these kind of approaches, I assume that you usually deal with low-complexity, not-variable problems. You can continue doing it but shouldn't think that what works under your (simpler) conditions works on other contexts. I usually deal with complex situations and this is an advice for complex situations.